# Relative path in layer styles in spatialite

Tags: qgis, spatialite, file-path

is there way to store default style in relative path in spatialite??it has layer styles table,and a column  'f_table_catalog'.and in this column pathes are absolute,In Qgis project options i set relative path.
If i move .sqlite to another directory and load the data then qgis doesn't see default style. and this "hand-made" procedure to load styles for every layer is annoying.

Comment: I tried many variants, no luck with this. https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Comment: When I move the sqlite db, I just update the 'f_table_catalog' with an up-to date path with field calculator - it works at least.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Spatialite_GUI 2.0.0-devel.  If you set the `f_table_catalog` to `NULL` in layer_styles, you can move the `.sqlite` to another directory and the default styles still apply in QGIS

Update - this works in QGIS 2.14, but not in 2.18